# VisualStudio: Please help interpreting debug output

Tags: vb.net, debugging, crash

One of the users of my application is complaining that he can't open the application.
He gave me the debug output of the crashed application...unfortunately I'm not an expert and have difficulties to manage it...would you please give me some help and help me understand why the application is crashing on his system?

Thanks!!!

---

**Callstack:**

```
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() + 0xac bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state) + 0x38 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x41 bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() + 0x5b bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() + 0x16b bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x5a bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) + 0x9b bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) + 0x6b bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) + 0x56 bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) + 0x3a bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) + 0x10e bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) + 0xf1 bytes   
[Native to Managed Transition]   
[Managed to Native Transition]   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0xae bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) + 0x49 bytes   
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run() + 0x4b bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore) + 0x17 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x6f bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window) + 0x26 bytes   
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run() + 0x1b bytes   
myapplication.exe!myapplication.Application.Main() + 0x54 bytes
```

**Debug Output:**

> 'myapplication.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'myapplication.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'myapplication.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\myapplication\Interop.WMPLib.dll',
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'myapplication.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):
>   Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll' C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll:
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll:
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should know more about your user environment (Operating system, running applications, ...) because it maybe just using shared resource with other applications or like that